# MySQL is still using the old server instance that I have deleted for good

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am facing problem of connecting to Mysql Server 8.0.15 even though I have upgraded everything from 8.0.13 to 8.0.14 and to 8.015.  Furthermore, I have deleted, using Administrator's right all the server folder inside C:\ProgramData\MySQL and now only left with the copy of 8.0.15.

So, I am stumped that when I run my usual connectivity to MySQL 8.0.15 server using MySQL workbench, the console is showing server 8.0.14.

In addition, I have also removed the services in Windows 10 by using sc delete MySQLserviceName.

I hope someone can tell me how to let MySQLWorkbench know it is supposed to connect with MySQL server 8.0.15 and not the deleted ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is no remaining **mysqld** process running?
If you connect trough terminal, and execute:

```
SELECT VERSION();
```

What is the response?